# Exponential function with a sum of 1

Tags: functions, power-series, exponential-function

I have a problem where I have $n$-elements and the size of these elements must be $1$ all together (sum), but they need to be exponentially sized.

Lets say I have $5$ elements, the first one needs to be $0.5$, $2$nd $0.25$, $3$rd $0.15$, $4$th $7$, $5$th $3$ (the sizes should be proportionally distributed, but the first one should be $0.5$).

I have tried to implement [exponential decay](https://mathmalfunctions.wordpress.com/exponential-functions/exponential-decay/), but how can I set it as a sum? Should I solve this problem in any other way...with exponential series?

I am a developer and I don't have an idea how to solve this math problem. The solution should look as a chart graph where the next bar is lower than the previous one, but they need to have a combined height of $1$.

Help appreciated!

Comment: After 2 years and 7 months (!!) being a member of this site I'd say it is about time to write mathematics properly...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, anyone can be a member...it doesn't imply that I need to master it. However I forgot many stuff...

Comment: True...and the fact is you already got your answer and that's what matters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a geometric series. Say you have a starting element $a$, then your terms are given by $ar^n$ for $n = 0,...,N-1$, where $N$ is the total number of elements. You then have that
$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}ar^n = \frac{a(r^N-1)}{r-1} = 1.$$
Given $N$, then solve for $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Example.** Let $a = 1/2$ be the starting element and $N = 5$. Then
$$\frac12\frac{r^5-1}{r-1} = 1\quad\quad\implies\quad\quad r=0.518790... $$

Your terms are then $(1/2)\cdot (0.518790...)^n$ for $n = 0,...,4$, i.e.
$$0.5,\quad 0.2593950318..., \quad 0.134571565..., \quad 0.06981439...,\quad 0.03621901...$$

Comment: Thank you for your quick and correct response! :) I guess i was looking in wrong direction. This is then possible to resolve with any other series also in a similar manner as i understand?

Comment: If your start element is $a$ and your total number of elements is $N$, then you simply need to solve
$$\frac{a(r^N-1)}{r-1} = 1.$$
If $a$ and $N$ are given, then we only need to find $r$ and this should work in general.

Comment: Yes I understood that...thank you for the in depth explanation.